# Symfony2 & Blueimp/jQueryFileUpload : How to implement the Default uploader?

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I want to implement the Blueimp/jQueryFileUploader in Symfony 2.2. I found a bundle but it doesn't actually work on Symfony2 (not supported yet according to the creator).

Anyway, I want to use in my application the Default version of that uploader. I added the files to the bundles folder of /web, and I can see the page that contains the buttons in Bootstrap. But when it comes to Javascript, it just throws this exception :

`Unexpected character ";" in SitePersoBundle:Default:file_upload.html.twig at line 77
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Syntax`

the line 77 contains :

```
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
```

All I did is copy/paste the source code of the demo so I can test, but it throws the  exception above. Why is that ?

Here's the link to the jQuery uploader on Github : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: So.. does anybody have an idea ??

Comment: Yes, why do you put `for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) {` inside blocks ( `{%` `%}` ) ?

Comment: I didn't, it's how the script is written. Check out the source code : http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Both use `{%` and `%}` as delimiters, that's the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mark the template as [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) to rpevnt Twig from trying to interpret it:

```
{% verbatim %}
    The template
{% endverbatim %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the twig verbatim tag removed the errors for me, but I still had trouble getting the plugin to work.

The solution was to [change the template engine](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Template-Engine), as per the documentation.